# How to fix my while statement so it doesn't terminate due to a memory issue

Tags: swift, while-loop, swift3

So I'm in the early stages of making an incremental game, I've been doing testing to understand how I could make the upgrades and such work.  I'm trying to have it happen that when you buy the first upgrade it adds 1 coin every second, but the while statement is giving me this error in the debugger "Terminated due to memory issue" I believe this is due to the while statement.  Please help and thanks!

```
  //
//  MainMenuScene.swift
//  SoloPlane
//
//  Created by -Zach on 7/27/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 -Zach. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import GameController



let defaults = UserDefaults()
var coins = defaults.integer(forKey: "coinsSaved")
let coinLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
var upgrade1 = defaults.integer(forKey: "upgrade1Saved")

class MainMenuScene: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    //var backingAudio = AVAudioPlayer()

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    background.size = self.size
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    background.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(background)


    let gameTitle1 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    gameTitle1.text = "The Kingdom"
    gameTitle1.fontSize = 200
    gameTitle1.fontColor = SKColor.darkGray
    gameTitle1.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: self.size.height*0.9)
    gameTitle1.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(gameTitle1)



    let Shop = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    Shop.text = "Shop"
    Shop.fontSize = 125
    Shop.fontColor = SKColor.darkGray
    Shop.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: self.size.height*0.3)
    Shop.zPosition = 1
    Shop.name = "Shop"
    self.addChild(Shop)

    let beginGame = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    beginGame.text = "Coins"
    beginGame.fontSize = 150
    beginGame.fontColor = SKColor.darkGray
    beginGame.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: self.size.height*0.4)
    beginGame.zPosition = 1
    beginGame.name = "Coins"
    self.addChild(beginGame)

    let Game = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
    Game.text = "Upgrade1"
    Game.fontSize = 150
    Game.fontColor = SKColor.darkGray
    Game.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: self.size.height*0.2)
    Game.zPosition = 1
    Game.name = "Upgrade1"
    self.addChild(Game)

    coinLabel.text = "Coins: \(coins)"
    coinLabel.fontSize = 100
    coinLabel.fontColor = SKColor.black
    coinLabel.zPosition = 1
    coinLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.1)
    self.addChild(coinLabel)

    //if backingAudio.playing {




    /*
     let settings = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "The Bold Font")
     settings.text = "Settings"
     settings.fontSize = 150
     settings.fontColor = SKColor.darkGrayColor()
     settings.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.5, y: self.size.height*0.3)
     settings.zPosition = 1
     settings.name = "settings"
     self.addChild(settings)

     */





    while upgrade1 >= 1{
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1) ) {
        coins += 1
    }
    }
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        let nodeITapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)

        if nodeITapped.name == "Coins" {
            coins += 1
            coinLabel.text = "Coins: \(coins)"

            defaults.set(coins, forKey: "coinsSaved")

            /*let sceneToMoveTo = GameScene(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTrasition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTrasition)*/



                    }
                    if nodeITapped.name == "Upgrade1" {
                        upgrade1 += 1
                        defaults.set(upgrade1, forKey: "upgrade1Saved")

        }


        if nodeITapped.name == "wood" {


           /* let sceneToMoveTo = ShopScene(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTrasition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTrasition) */


        }
        if nodeITapped.name == "Credits" {

      /*
            let sceneToMoveTo = CreditsScene(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTrasition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTrasition) */

        }


        while (upgrade1 == 1){
            //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1) ) {
            sleep(1)
                upgrade1 += 1
                coins += 1
                coinLabel.text = "Coins: \(coins)"

                defaults.set(coins, forKey: "coinsSaved")
            }


    }




}

}
```

Comment: Use an NSTimer instead of a while loop

Comment: @WMios How exactly would I use an NSTimer?

Comment: There's a trick to using `sleep`: don't use `sleep`. ever.

Comment: I haven't really used NSTimer or Sleep, I really don't know what to use there, I really need to figure out this while problem though.

Comment: @WMios I don't see any reason to use NSTimer over DispatchQueue

Comment: Can anyone actually help me solve the debugger error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you were trying to use DispatchQueue and asyncAfter but don't know the right way to do it.

You can have a async helper method call that itself recursively to achieve the async while effect.

```
func update () {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1) ) {
        if upgrade1 == 1 {
            self.upgrade1 += 1
            self.coins += 1
            self.coinLabel.text = "Coins: \(coins)"

            self.defaults.set(coins, forKey: "coinsSaved")

            self.update() // schedule another update after 1 second
        }
    }
}
```

and replace the while loop with `update()`

You may need to tweak the position of `if upgrade1 == 1`

Comment: @Bryan_Chen so bascially an if statement with that function inside of it?

Comment: and the function call itself to make a loop

Comment: @Bryan_Chen It works perfectly, but a new problem has arised.  I want it so when the player opens the app they don't have to buy the upgrade to start, it starts by itself as long as the upgrade1 > 1, Can you help me with calling this at the start?

Comment: Nevermind, Thank you very much I figured out how to do it.  Any easy way to get hold of you if I have more problems?

Comment: you can just post a new question and I will try to answer it

Comment: @Bryan_Chen I'm pretty sure it is, but is it possible to make table view, for a shop scene, I've looked around a bit, but most of the stuff seems outdated.